# Nifi Jolt Transform Spec

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to use nifi jolttransformjson to transform my JSON.
I'm playing around using this site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-stringFunctions

I have a JSON

```
{
"response": {
"Attribute": [
  {
    "id": "670868",
    "another_id": "8385",
    "category": "A",
    "type": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "670870",
    "another_id": "8385",
    "category": "B",
    "type": "abc"
  }
]
}
}
```

My Jolt Spec is

```
enter code here 
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "response": {
    "Attribute": {
      "*": {
        "type": "TYPE",
        "category": "CATEGORY"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
]
```

Current Output is

```
{
  "TYPE" : [ "abc", "abc" ],
  "CATEGORY" : [ "A", "B" ]
}
```

Wanted output is

```
[
   {
      "TYPE":"abc",
      "CATEGORY":"A"
   },
   {
      "TYPE":"abc",
      "CATEGORY":"B"
   }
]
```

Help please. I tried so many combinations and I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Map to List`](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#mapToList) example and you will find out solution:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "response": {
        "Attribute": {
          "*": {
            "@type": "[#2].TYPE",
            "@category": "[#2].CATEGORY"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. For some reason, I was using examples 6, 7, 11, 12, 13. I didn't realize it was in # 5's. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "response" : {
        "Attribute" : {
          "*" : {
            "type" : "[&1].TYPE",
            "category" : "[&1].CATEGORY"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```